# JDBC Connection from Ubuntu 11.10 to Amazon EC2 BitNami LampStack instance - Access Denied (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, amazon-ec2

- My local machine is running Ubuntu 11.10.  I use Eclipse Indigo as my IDE.
- My server is a BitNami LampStack (Ubuntu 10) running on Amazon EC2.
- I am relatively experienced in both .Net and Java, but **a beginner in JDBC, MySQL Administration, Linux, and EC2**.

I have successfully opened port 3306, and MySQL Workbench can connect correctly.  User 'root'@'%' has full privileges to everything, and no default database.

After struggling with a no-suitable-driver-found issue, I finally just put the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar directly in my Java Project.  I realize this is probably sub-optimal, but it seems to work.  I did it (after much Googling) because I can't figure out how to install it correctly on Ubuntu, and am worried it will be harder through ssh to EC2, so I figured it could just compile into the project.  A link would be appreciated, as it would be nice to fix that also.

The following is the code that throws the Exception.  This is at the top of main; nothing executes first.

I have tried this with and without the Class.forName(...) and also using a java.util.Properties for the credentials.  Identical credentials work from MySQL Workbench on same machine, which I have copy+pasted several times to ensure no typos.

I altered the passwords and addresses for the sake of security, though keeping the format.  To be explicit, the password here is "Abcdef1234#".  For all I know, the # may be the culprit.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String CONNECTION_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://ec2-87-212-16-34.compute-1.amazonaws.com?user=root&password=Abcdef1234#";
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
```

Which then throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'ppp-72-135-32-239.dsl.hgyuct.swbell.net' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3421)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1247)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:222)
at Program.main(Program.java:5)
```

Let me know if I should include any more information.

Comment: Is this your real server details? If it is so, replace those with fake values in this post. (except special chars)

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  Yeah, I already altered all the ip addresses and passwords.

Comment: Note: I just discovered that MySQL Workbench's Administration Data Export features do not work from my local machine, however, they do when I build an ssh repeater from my port 7777 to the EC2 port 3306 and then tell MySQL Administrator to point to localhost:7777 from my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `'root'@'localhost'` password was different than the `'root'@'%'` password, so connecting from JDBC used what I thought was the old password.